# Firebase Realtime Database Rules. Only creator can read data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

### This is my Database:

```json
{
  "categories": {
    "c-NgA8_ZDjEur3HowEFVD": {
      "create_date": 1696699144485,
      "creator": "Codw8lfHuDcUox1Xe4ima15OGXi1",
      "delete_date": "",
      "description": "Am Abend ein schönes Nachtessen",
      "title": "Nachtessen",
      "update_date": ""
    }
  },
  "ideas": {
    "i-NgAD6p5s8G5rJWAQo48": {
      "category": "c-NgA8_ZDjEur3HowEFVD",
      "create_date": 1696700333404,
      "creator": "Codw8lfHuDcUox1Xe4ima15OGXi1",
      "delete_date": "",
      "description": "Essen im Vito in Zürich",
      "title": "Essen im Vito",
      "update_date": ""
    }
  }
}
```

### This are my Rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "categories": {
      ".indexOn": ["creator"],
      "$category_id": {
        ".read": "data.child('creator').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    },
    "ideas": {
      ".indexOn": ["creator"],
      "$idea_id": {
        ".read": "data.child('creator').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### React Typescript Code:

```js
 const categoriesRefOrdered = query(
        categoriesRef,
        orderByChild('creator'),
        equalTo(account.uid),
      );
      const unsubscriber = onValue(categoriesRefOrdered, (snapshot) => {
        const val: CategoriesObjectType = snapshot.val();
        if (val) {
          const array = objectToArray(val);
          dispatch(initCategories(array));
        } else {
          dispatch(initCategories(null));
        }
      });
```

I tried the same without the $category_id row.

"creator" String is the users uid. And my try is to only let the creator read his data.

I tried this for debuging:

**Simulation results**
**Inquiry details**

```json
{
  "auth": {
    "uid": "Codw8lfHuDcUox1Xe4ima15OGXi1",
    "token": {
      "sub": "Codw8lfHuDcUox1Xe4ima15OGXi1",
      "firebase": {
        "sign_in_provider": "password"
      },
      "email": "",
      "email_verified": false
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "path": "/categories",
  "method": "get",
  "time": "2023-10-09T13:07:39.316Z",
  "isAdmin": false
}
```

**Result details**
Line 5 (/categories)
read: "data.child('creator').val() === auth.uid"

Comment: Security rules don't do anything until you execute code agiainst them. Please edit your question to [include a code snippet that doesn't do what you expect it to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo
Do you need something more?

Comment: How is `categoriesRef` defined?

Comment: @AlexMamo 
const db = getDatabase(); 
const categoriesRef = ref(db, 'categories'); 
But this is not my Problem, when i change the rules to ".read": "true" i get the categories back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to read data from the `categories` path in your database, but your security rules don't grant anyone read access to that path - so the rules reject the query.

To [securely query the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) you'll want something like this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "categories": {
      ".indexOn": ["creator"],
      ".read": "auth.uid !== null &&
            query.orderByChild === 'creator' &&
            query.equalTo === auth.uid",
      ...
```

Now the rules allow the user to read `categories` as long as the filter on `creator` having the same value as their own UID, which you code seems to do.

Comment: The rules need the same settings as the js query? And how do I know that parameters like query.equalTo exist? Is there a documentation somewhere about this?

Comment: Did you click the link to the documentation that I included in my answer? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯